# Python http.server cant be accessed by other PCs in same network

Tags: python, flutter, http, web, server

I am trying to run a flutter web app through a simple python http server. My web app root directory contains a index.html and all required files for the app.
If I try to host the app through a python http.server via

```
py -m http.server --bind <my-ip-address>
```

I can access the app on my PC on "my-ip-address:8000".
No other PC in the network is able to reach the server. The terminal is displaying no request whatsoever.

Comment: Did you allow access in the firewall?

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggested, the firewall was the problem.